# Query for document id within a collection with multiple documents

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `artworks` with two documents:

kvAKyzz8duHJefihekpr

```
artist: "Pablo Picasso"
status: true
```

pCETdBNd0B6nm60BD15b

```
artist: "Franz Klein"
status: true
```

**Question**
How do I grab the document id (e.g., `kvAKyzz8duHJefihekpr`) from the collection **and then** pass it in as a prop?

```js
const [artworks, setArtworks] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("artworks").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
      setArtworks(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="review__board">
      
      <div>
        {artworks.map((artwork) => (
          <ReviewCard
            artist={artwork.artist}
           // pass in id as a prop??? id={artwork.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

In other words, how can I query for the document id within a collection and then use it as a prop?

Here is the shape of my collection:

[image]

Comment: What's the *specific* shape of the collection. Copy paste it in the question

Comment: @Jayce444 Just updated the question with a picture :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
db.collection("artworks").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
  setArtworks(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
);
```

I like to use Object.defineProperty to have the `id` attach to the data. That way when write back to Firestore I will not have `id` field in the database (unless you intended to use it).

```
const fromFirestore = (doc) => {
  const data = doc.data();
  Object.defineProperty(data, 'id', {value: doc.id})
  return data;
}

db.collection("artworks").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
  setArtworks(snapshot.docs.map(fromFirestore))
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am going to use the id. Your first bit of code doesn't seem to work in the useEffect. Can you look at it again?

Comment: demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/long-shadow-boltp . Please careful enter your config.